# For loop use in R to use multiple files in a directory

Tags: r

I have multiple files coded by id number in a directory. each file has four variables. One of the variable has same id number as that of file. I need to run a function mean for one of the other three variables, using each of the file.

I am a beginner learner. So far I have seen from this website and others, that how to use for and if loops to use data from a single file. I have tried many combinations. One of this is as follows. However, I am not getting the desired output. Can you guide?

```
pollutantmean<- function (directory, pollutant, id = 1:332){


    directory  = "~/specdata" 
    pollutant = "sulfate"
    for (i in 1:332){         
        pollutantmean (directory [i])
        options(expressions=1000) 
        }
        means
}
```

`id` is the idnumber of each file contained in a directory "`specdata`" at my working directory and pollutant is the variable that will be used by either of two variables- sulfate and nitrate  in datasets

However, when running

```
pollutantmean()
```

I get

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion /
>   options(expressions=)? Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too
>   deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Comment: i have edited your post in an attempt to make your function definition clearer. If this is not what you wanted, please click edit and replace it with something appropriate.

Comment: First read your data in, then analyze it. You're not going to realize if there are issues with it until it's read in with `read.table` or whatnot. As-is, what's the point of the recursive call of `pollutantmean`? What is `means`? Why are you including parameters in your function definition if you're overriding or not using them?

Comment: Use `list.files` (or `paste()`) to get (or construct) strings for each file name. Then anything you can do with one file you should be able to to do many files in the loop. Just treat the file name as a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a proposed solution:

(i) create a list of file names in R (presuming that the files are in *.txt format.

```
files<-list.files(pattern="\\.txt")
```

You may want to state the directory and grab the full pathname if the files are not residing in your working directory:

```
list.files(path="e:/data", pattern="\\.txt", full.names=T)
```

(ii) read the tables into a list:

```
tmp<-lapply(files, function(x) read.table(x, header=T))
```

(iii) calculate mean of sulphate for each table within the list:

```
sapply(1:length(tmp), function(x) mean(tmp[[x]]$sulfate, na.rm=T))
```

Comment: lapply() will definitely speed this up as well, nice

Comment: No need for an anonymous function for reading the files, just pass `header = T` to `...` like this: `tmp <- lapply(files, read.table, header = T)`