# Keep name into list

Tags: r

I am uploading multiple files containing the same type of information but different values. Then I create a list to manage the data easier with:

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "D:/Paths",
                        pattern = "path-+.*txt")
```

`paths <- lapply(filenames, function(x) read.delim(x, header=F))`

But the name of the `paths` disappear once I execute the second command, any suggestion to keep the name for each dataframe inside the list()?

Comment: Try with `setNames` or `names` i.e. `names(paths) <- filenames`

Comment: In particular, you can do `lapply(setNames(, filenames), function(x) ...)`

Comment: I am trying [to do what they explain in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880068/for-loop-use-in-r-to-use-multiple-files-in-a-directory) but names keep disappearing. I tried with your suggestions but I get the following error: `Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sapply` which keeps names by default. Also no need for an anonymous function, you can just pass `header = F` through with `...` like this:

```
paths = sapply(filenames, read.delim, header = F, simplify = FALSE)
```

(`simplify = FALSE` ensures that you get a `list` output just like `lapply`.)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much Gregor!